# How do I use a variable using get_range method C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

I want to use get_Range in C# to start at column "K14:K21". Since every sheet that I read in will be different in length I set a variable to find the number of the last row.

This code works

```
if (ws.get_Range("K14:K21").Value != null)
```

---

What I'm wanting to do - doesn't work

```
int lastRow = rowRange.Rows.Count;
if (ws.get_Range("K14:K + lastRow").Value != null)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: When I debug I can see that lastRow variable equals 21.

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"? Is there any error message? Could you please edit your question and past it there?

Comment: Why are you using `get_Range` instead of [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-range-property-excel) ? Did you use the Interop libraries? Did you try adding a COM reference directly and calling the getters/setters of the properties instead of the properties themselves?

Comment: The description of `get_Range` is `Gets a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range object that represents a cell or a range of cells. Use the Range property instead of this method.` Emphasis on `Use the Range property instead of this method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I was able to get it to work using the code like this.

```
if (ws.get_Range("K14:K"+ lastRow.ToString()).Value != null)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a typo in your `if` condition. Instead of

```
if (ws.get_Range("K14:K + lastRow").Value != null)
```

Try

```
if (ws.get_Range("K14:K" + lastRow).Value != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you add `lastRow` as string parameter. If you want to do this, you must do in one of the following ways:

1.
`if (ws.get_Range("K14:K" + lastRow).Value != null)`

2.
`if (ws.get_Range($"K14:K{lastRow}").Value != null)`

3.
`if (ws.get_Range(string.Format("K14:K{0}", lastRow)).Value != null)`